# How to merge two nodes as one in forest?

Tags: forest

I would like to merge nodes [Bye1 and Bye2] as Bye 3 in the following MWE.

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
           l sep+=5pt,
             inner sep=1.5pt,
              grow'=east,
            font=\sffamily, edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, draw=darkgray, align=center, anchor=children},
  before packing={where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
  before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
  where level<=0{line width=1pt}{line width=1pt},
  [Testing 
[Hello,
] 
[Bye, 
[Bye1]
[Bye2]
]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by “merge”? Do you you want it to be one node or do you want them to have a common child?

Comment: I want to merge Bye1 and Bye2 such that they have one common child Bye 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `Bye3` node a child of `Bye2` and then `\draw` the missing edge. You can set `y` for `Bye3` to be the same as for `Bye` using `before drawing tree={y=y("!uu")}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
           l sep+=5pt,
             inner sep=1.5pt,
              grow'=east,
            font=\sffamily, edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, draw=darkgray, align=center, anchor=children},
  before packing={where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
  before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
  where level<=0{line width=1pt}{line width=1pt},
[Testing 
    [Hello] 
    [Bye, 
        [Bye1, name=B1]
        [Bye2
            [Bye3, name=B3, before drawing tree={y=y("!uu")}]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[darkgray, line width=1pt] (B1.east)--++(\forestoption{fork sep},0)|-(B3);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```